# Регулярные выражения в PHP. Многострочный поиск

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Возникла проблема, нужно с помощью регулярного выражения извлечь текст заключенный между блоками.
Сейчас делаю так:

```
/(?<=<div id=\"summary\" class=\"\">\n)(.+)(?=\n<\/div>)/ui
```

Но ничего не получается, если добавить модификатор `\s` то извлекается текст от начала нужного блока, но до конца текста:

```
/(?<=<div id=\"summary\" class=\"\">\n)(.+)(?=\n<\/div>)/uis
```

Текст поиска:

```html
<div class="hp_hotel_description_hightlights_wrapper">
  <div class="hotel_description_wrapper_exp">
    <div id="summary" class=""> <!--Начать тут -->
      <p>Offering a terrace and a lounge area, Abkhazskaya Usadba is located in Gagra, 500 metres from the Black Sea coast. Free WiFi and free private parking are available on site.</p>
      <p>The rooms feature a balcony, private entrance, air conditioning, a fridge, hairdryer and flat-screen TV.</p>
      <p>Guests can dine in the guest house’s canteen serving home made food.</p>
      <p>Gagra Train Station is 2 km away, and Sochi International Airport is 40 km from Abkhazskaya Usadba.</p>
    </div> <!-- Закончить тут -->
    <p class="summary " style="color: #555; font-size: 95%; font-style: italic; ">
      Hotel Rooms: 24
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="property_hightlights_wrapper">
    <div class="property_highlights_left">
      <div class="photo_overlay filter_api_vers_left filter_api_width">
        <span class="inner_content_filter_api">
<p class="filter_highlights_title ">
Property Highlights
</p>
<span rel="300" class="lastbooking jq_tooltip" title="&lt;strong&gt;Double or Twin Room with Shower&lt;&#47;strong&gt; booked 1 day, 15 hours, 41 minutes ago">
Latest Booking: May 4
</span>
        <span class="highlighted_facilities_reinforcement highlighted_facilities_property_reinforcement">
<p class="filter_api_subtitle">
</p>
</span>
        <span class="hp_usp_filter_api_el">
<i class="b-sprite hotelfacility_id_96"></i>
<span class="hp_usp_filter_api_text">
Free WiFi
</span>
        </span>
        <span class="hp_usp_filter_api_el">
<i class="b-sprite hotelfacility_id_2"></i>
<span class="hp_usp_filter_api_text">
Free parking
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярные выражения плохо подходят для парсинга HTML по ряду причин. Для парсинга HTML корректней применять парсеры, написанные специально для этой задачи, например, [symfony/dom-crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) вместе с symfony/css-selector:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$element = $crawler->filter('#summary')->eq(0);
// искомое значение
$contents = $element->nodeValue;
```

Писал по документации, возможно, в некоторых местах требуются корректировки.

Comment: Вопрос все еще стоит, мне нужно именно с использованием регулярного выражения сделать, потому что большую часть уже сделал с использованием регулярок, остался единственный недоделанный. `/(?<=div id=\"summary\" class=\"\">)(.*)(?=<\/div>)/us`  С начала строки все нормально работает но почему-то конец неправильно обрабатывает, идет вниз до конца страницы. Помогите очень нужно, потом обещаю больше не буду так делать, буду пользоваться Crawler))))

Comment: @ElSalvadore попробуйте заменить `(.+)` на `(.+?)` или `([^<]+)`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью поддерживаю @Etki в том, что регулярные выражения не подходят для парсинга HTML.

В качестве альтернативного решения предлагаю использовать встроенный в PHP классы [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) и [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpathSummary = new DOMXPath($doc);
# Выбираем первый элемент удовлетворяющий условию и показываем его текстовое содержимое
var_dump($xpathSummary->query("//div[@id='summary']")->item(0)->textContent);
```

Обратите внимание на этот hack: "[как загрузить html в UTF-8](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251)".

[Посмотреть рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/28XFN6)